# How to create a shortcut to a letter in keyboard Linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I have a broken <kbd>s</kbd> key on my laptop's keyboard. It is impossible to fix it. How can I create a shortcut for "s" to overcome this issue?

```
ID_LIKE="ubuntu debian"
PRETTY_NAME="Linux Mint 21.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can type the unicode values for all the letters.

The shortcut for s:
Hold the Ctrl+SHFT keys type u0073 then let go the Ctrl+SHFT keys

For S:
Hold the Ctrl+SHFT keys type u0053 then let go the Ctrl+SHFT keys

You can get the unicode for any letter from the CHARMAP app

Comment: Welcome to U&L, and thanks for your contribution. Unfortunately this answer is incorrect. The OP is asking how to create a kbd shortcut for letter s. For example CTRL+C is a kbd shortcut. What you're showing is how to create a character using its unicode value. Entirely different ballgame - try typing "Mississippi missus" 10 times with just the unicode value of s...

Comment: I see your point but, as you mentioned, CTRL+C is and CTRL+V is as well - so once he's got the first 's' he can simply copy it and paste it as many times as he likes. Clunky I know but in the absence of a simpler solution, itś a work-round. :-)

Comment: It is, both clunky and a workaround as there are ways to remap keys :-) You should re-word this, tho', replace the "use a keyboard shortcut" with "type the characters with unicode values" or something like that.

Comment: No-one seems to have come up with a method for re-mapping keys per the OP's request though...

Comment: Funny enough yes :-) The method does depend on the desktop manager, which isn't given.